File input adapter not polling/processing the same file despite removing it from AcceptOnceFileListFilter
I created the AcceptOnceFileListFilter bean in xml and reference that inside ChainFileListFilter below is the order of my chain filters

ChainListFilter
RegexPatternFileListFilter
AcceptOnceFileListFilter

The issue is I make a java class and
@Autowired public ChainFileListFilter<File> chainFilter 
@Autowired public AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File> acceptOnceFilter

public void clearCache(@Payload File file) {
    chainFilter.remove(file);
    acceptOnceFilter.remove(file);

}

Testing: I create 2 files with the same name and placed them in the directory once the first file is processed. However, the 2nd file stays in the directory. I'm pretty sure it was removed in the hashset since I did if(acceptOnceFilter.remove(file) print x else print y twice and it went into the else statement the second time.

If your AcceptOnceFileListFilter is a part of ChainFileListFilter, then it is indeed called twice. Because ChainFileListFilter delegates to its chain of filters.

If I understand your correctly, here is a test demonstrating that it works as expected:
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.io.TempDir;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.InboundChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Poller;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptOnceFileListFilter;
import org.springframework.integration.file.filters.ChainFileListFilter;
import org.springframework.integration.file.filters.SimplePatternFileListFilter;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringJUnitConfig;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@SpringJUnitConfig
@DirtiesContext
public class So78619680Tests {

    @TempDir
    static File WORK_DIR;

    @Autowired
    ChainFileListFilter<File> fileChainFileListFilter;

    @Autowired
    QueueChannel processFileChannel;

    @Test
    void sameFileNameWithDifferentContentIsProcessed() throws IOException {
        File testFile = new File(WORK_DIR, "test.txt");
        FileUtils.write(testFile, "test content", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        Message<?> receivedMessage = this.processFileChannel.receive(10_000);

        assertThat(receivedMessage).isNotNull();
        assertThat(receivedMessage.getPayload()).isInstanceOf(File.class);
        File processedFile = (File) receivedMessage.getPayload();
        assertThat(processedFile).hasFileName("test.txt").content(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).isEqualTo("test content");
        assertThat(this.fileChainFileListFilter.remove(testFile)).isTrue();

        FileUtils.write(testFile, "another data", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        receivedMessage = this.processFileChannel.receive(10_000);

        assertThat(receivedMessage).isNotNull();
        assertThat(receivedMessage.getPayload()).isInstanceOf(File.class);
        processedFile = (File) receivedMessage.getPayload();
        assertThat(processedFile).hasFileName("test.txt").content(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).isEqualTo("another data");
        assertThat(this.fileChainFileListFilter.remove(testFile)).isTrue();
    }

    @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
    @EnableIntegration
    public static class TestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        ChainFileListFilter<File> fileChainFileListFilter() {
            return new ChainFileListFilter<>(
                    List.of(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.txt"), new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>()));
        }

        @Bean
        QueueChannel processFileChannel() {
            return new QueueChannel();
        }

        @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "processFileChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000"))
        @Bean
        FileReadingMessageSource fileReadingMessageSource(ChainFileListFilter<File> fileChainFileListFilter) {
            FileReadingMessageSource fileReadingMessageSource = new FileReadingMessageSource();
            fileReadingMessageSource.setDirectory(WORK_DIR);
            fileReadingMessageSource.setFilter(fileChainFileListFilter);
            return fileReadingMessageSource;
        }

    }

}

So, I modify the same file and remove it from the filter. Therefore a new message is received with new content from the same file.
If we don't remove from the filter, the new content is not received.

Hmm when I used just ChainFileListFilter.remove() it's always true even when I randomly do new File("random")
What I mean in original post
I have file apple.txt in two locations /apps/orangeService/ and /apps/lemonService and let's say my file input adapter is polling /apps/appleService/ directory. If I move apple.txt from orangeService to appleService. It works fine and it should call .remove() method after. So, now if I move apple.txt from lemonService to appleService IT SHOULD process again. But, in my case it doesn't.

Basically, what I need is AcceptOnceFileListFilter hashset should be EMPTY even If I process 10k files, since it should remove each file at the end of the flow per file process. So the functionality is essentially should me to multithread with taskExecutor without it looking like I'm using AcceptOnceFileListFilter

I'll try tomorrow. I think issue maybe because I'm not using @EnableIntegration and does works if half the stuff is in spring-integration.xml and only the remove code is in java right? Since you're example is full java.

I'm not sure why you would worry about true or false from the ChainFileListFilter. As long as you remove from there a file in the subject in the end of your process, it should work. Something is off with your application yet. The fact that you use XML configuration doesn't matter: at runtime it still the same FileReadingMessageSource and ChainFileListFilter.
